# How to switch back text encoding to UTF-8 with emacs?

Tags: emacs, encoding

Suddenly some of my text files, I'm editing with `Emacs` had changed and special characters were shown in a strange way, e. g.

`\344` instead of `ä`
`\374` instead of `ü`
... and so on.

In another file I now have

`Ã¼` for `ü`
`Ã¤` for `ä`
....

(I don't know which event was the cause for that, maybe I've been doing something wrong.)

I'd like to convert the document back to its original state (my standard encoding is UTF-8), so that it is displayed correctly with ä, ö, ü, ... but I do not know how to do that with emacs.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you haven't changed the file, you can try `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system`. One of `latin-1` or `utf-8` should work, depending on the file.

You can also mark the entire file with `C-x h` and then try `M-x recode-region`.  It will ask you for `Text was really in` and `But was interpreted as`.  For the first file in your question, it looks like it should be `latin-1` and `utf-8`, and for the second example it should probably be the other way around, `utf-8` and `latin-1`.

After you got it right, you can choose which coding system to save the file with using `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system` (or `C-x C-m f` for short).

Comment: Unfortunately, I need that command quite often, so I'd like to define a keyboard shortcut to invoke recode-region (orig: latin-1, interpreted as utf-8-dos) with one keystroke. How can I define a little program, which does that and which I can map to a key?

Comment: You could record it as a macro, and then name, bind and save it as described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html

Comment: `C-x RET f utf-8` also works.

Comment: TLDR, open a file, use `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system` to change the file encoding then save.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is:

C-x RET r utf-8 RET

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation ('which event was the cause, etc') and why your solution works with detail and easy to follow instructions (the OP may or may not understand what needs to be done and future readers could also be unsure). If you feel your answer is correct please do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I tried the top answer above, but it didn't quite entirely fix my problem. So to add onto that...

If the problem persists when you re-open the file, it could also be due to the variable enable-multibyte-characters being nil.

A new buffer will usually have this as t (which is why you can paste utf-8 characters into the buffer hassle-free).

To fix this, you'll need to do something like: (set-buffer-multibyte 't)

The result should be instantaneous.