# Change encoding of a text file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, encoding

Emacs shows in a text file:

> Given a finite alphabet \246\262, (empty set) \2016\3221 denoting the set \2016\3221.

But it should show

> Given a finite alphabet Σ, (empty set) ∅ denoting the set ∅.

What should I do to make Emacs show the text correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what encoding that is, but perhaps the suggestions in [this question](http://superuser.com/q/549497/4542) might help.